# Given a sequence of positive numbers An such that the series k=1 to infinity {ak} is convergent. Is the series k=1 to infinity cos(ak +

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a sequence of positive numbers $\{a_n\}$ such that the series

$$\sum_{k=1} ^\infty a_k$$
is convergent. Is the series

$$\sum_{k=1} ^\infty \cos(a_k + \pi)$$

convergent ? 
(Show all the steps of your work)

No idea where to start, any help is appreciated!

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: $$\cos(x+\pi)=\cos x\cos \pi-\sin x\sin \pi=-\cos x\neq-\sin x\ldots$$

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, of course. (Mixed up real and imaginary parts.)

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not convergent. By the $\textbf{n^th term test}$, because the series is convergent, $a_k$ converges to $0$. $$\cos(0+\pi)=-1 \ \ \ So\ \ \cos(a_k+\pi)\to-1  $$

Which obviously doesn't converge.

Comment: I don't really know how to write in LaTeX well. Sorry.

Comment: An intro to $\LaTeX$ here is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  There are other tutorials on the web.  You can right-click any piece and select Show Math As -> TeX Commands to see how it is done.